# Media Translator API not translating properly

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-api, translate

I am using Media Translator API. This API does not translate all the words in an audio file. I am getting only one words in the middle or starting of the media file. I am unable to get a complete sentence.

I have an mp3 file. This file have "Welcome to America.". But the Media Translator API only returns "America".

This is my code. Did I miss something? Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

```
const fs = require('fs');
// Imports the CLoud Media Translation client library
const {
  SpeechTranslationServiceClient,
} = require('@google-cloud/media-translation');

// Creates a client
const client = new SpeechTranslationServiceClient();

translate_from_file();

async function translate_from_file() {
  
  const filename = './like.mp3';
  const encoding = 'mp3';
  const sourceLanguage = 'en-US';
  const targetLanguage = 'it-IT';

  const config = {
    audioConfig: {
      audioEncoding: encoding,
      sourceLanguageCode: sourceLanguage,
      targetLanguageCode: targetLanguage
    },
    single_utterance: true,
  };

  // First request needs to have only a streaming config, no data.
  const initialRequest = {
    streamingConfig: config,
    audioContent: null,
  };

  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
    highWaterMark: 4096,
    encoding: 'base64',
  });

  const chunks = [];
  readStream
    .on('data', chunk => {
      // console.log(chunk)
      const request = {
        streamingConfig: config,
        audioContent: chunk.toString(),
      };
      chunks.push(request);
    })
    .on('close', () => {
      // Config-only request should be first in stream of requests
      stream.write(initialRequest);
      for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
        stream.write(chunks[i]);
      }
      stream.end();
    });

  const stream = client.streamingTranslateSpeech().on('data', response => {
    const {result} = response;
    if (result.textTranslationResult.isFinal) {
      console.log(
        `\nFinal translation: ${result.textTranslationResult.translation}`
      );
      console.log(`Final recognition result: ${result.recognitionResult}`);
    } else {
      console.log(
        `\nPartial translation: ${result.textTranslationResult.translation}`
      );
      console.log(`Partial recognition result: ${result.recognitionResult}`);
    }
  });
}
```